# Como imprimir em impressora térmica Bematech MP-4200 TH utilizando Javascript?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, impressora, porta-serial

Preciso imprimir um comprovante de venda através de uma aplicação web, onde desenvolvi o front utilizando Vuejs e o back construi uma API com o Laravél, e estou querendo integrar uma impressora bematech MP-4200 TH, pretendia fazer em uma chamada de função no meu componente do vuejs, mas achei muito pouco material sobre a integração da impressora com javascript, estou utilizando uma porta serial
, alguém sabe como posso fazer isso?

Comment: Pelo o que sei, com o javascript no lado do cliente, no caso a sua situação que está usando Vue.js, não é possível manipular o hardware da máquina, seria até falha de segurança caso fosse possível. Você teria que ter uma outra linguagem mais para o lado do backend para realizar essa ação.

Comment: O que você pode fazer caso tenha a impressora instalada no computador é fazer com que o usuário imprima, com a função https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_print.asp